# Wordpress / Bootstrap Menu

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to show the children of the current page/id in a navigation, and if they also have children then enable a dropdown. How do I do this using Wordpress/Bootstrap?

Comment: kind of a loaded question....

Comment: did you take a look at the wordpress codex? get_children might be helpful …

Answer (score 0):

Inset this code in your bootstrap html code in header.php

```
<?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse text-center drop',
        'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
    ?>
```

Get the [bootstrap walker](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) and add to your themes folder
Follow the instructions on github they are easy enough.

Example nav with the PHP content for walker.(ignore my menu code etc)

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Omertà <span class="logocol">Inc</span></a>
    </div>

 <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse text-center drop',
         'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );
        ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Then place this code in your functions.php page:

```
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

register_nav_menus( array(
'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'YOURTHEME' ),) );
```